# Pyspark application not able to run in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When ever i am running the following spark code, few of the runs it will fail with TimeoutException.

**test_spark_app.py**

```
print("importing libraries")
from pyspark import SparkContext
from datetime import datetime
print("finish importing libraries")
def printMessage(msg):
    print (datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") +" - " + msg)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext()
    printMessage("Application start")
    printMessage("Application end")
```

**TimeoutException**

```
20/10/21 11:10:59 INFO ApplicationMaster: Starting the user application in a separate Thread
20/10/21 11:10:59 INFO ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization...
20/10/21 11:11:29 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (989889899) connection to host1.mysite.com/182.25.26.29:8020 from streamf09w: closed
20/10/21 11:11:29 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (989889899) connection to host1.mysite.com/182.25.26.29:8020 from streamf09w: stopped, remaining connections 0
20/10/21 11:12:39 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$5.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:815)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:839)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
20/10/21 11:12:39 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13, (reason: Uncaught exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds])
20/10/21 11:12:39 DEBUG ApplicationMaster: shutting down user thread
```

**Container log:**

```
importing libraries
finish importing libraries
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hadoop/data/08/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/streamf10w/appcache/application_1603777923068_25093/container_e72_1603777923068_25184_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hadoop/data/08/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/streamf09w/appcache/application_1603777923068_25093/container_e72_1603777923068_25184_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/opt/hadoop/data/08/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/streamf10w/appcache/application_1603777923068_25093/container_e72_1603777923068_25184_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_spark_app.py", line 9, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext()
  File "/opt/hadoop/data/08/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/streamf09w/appcache/application_1603777923068_25093/container_e72_1603777923068_25184_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 119, in __init__
```

Comment: resource manager and node managers can interact with each other? are you sure there are no network problem?

Comment: Cluster is enabled with IPV6. I am suspecting this will cause the issue.